# TextView Marquee not showing '..'

Tags: android, textview, size, marquee

I already tryed alot of solutions, maxLine, maxLenght, marqueeAlwaysShowing, the ellipsize with marquee..the focusable thing.. I can't can't just get it working.

I erased all the additional XML to make it working and here it is, this is what I have:

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/promptDefine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/counterDefinitionName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="nameCounting"
            android:text="@string/nameIt"
            android:textColor="@color/count_item_to_be_defined"


         />


    </LinearLayout>
```

So, what should I have to add it at textview to limit text to 10 characters ? but if they are more just insert the "..." at the end. I already tryed some things like:

```
   android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

And didn't work, thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Maybe its the Clickable feature attribute that is messing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The three dot only shows when the textView doesn't have enough space for the characters.

in your case just set a fix width and set single line. then it should work.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/counterDefinitionName"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:onClick="nameCounting"
            android:text="@string/nameIt"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/count_item_to_be_defined" />
```

Comment: Wow ! you are amazing it works, but how can I refer to the amount of characters ? instead of using dip at width ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

not "clickable", make it "selected"

Comment: I need it to be clickable, there is a function being called when I click it.